# Add objects from one array to another array of objects. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

With the next **arrays**:

```js
let arr1 = [
  { name:"Elvira", projects_list: [ { id:1 }, { id:2 } ] },
  { name:"Sarah",  projects_list: [ { id:2 }, { id:5 } ] },
];
    
let arr2 = [
  { project_id:1, title: "title_1" },
  { project_id:2, title: "title_2" },
];
```

How can I add the elements of each `arr2` to the `projects_list` from `arr1`, where the `id` value matchs?
**The result should be**:

```js
let arr1 = [
  { name:"Elvira", projects_list: [ 
      { project_id:1,  title: "title_1" }, 
      { project_id:2,  title: "title_2" }
  ] },
  { name:"Sarah", projects_list: [ 
      { project_id:2,  title: "title_2" },
      { id:5 }, 
  ] }
];
```

I was trying something like this:

```js
arr1.forEach( r1 => 
  r1.projectsList.forEach( project => {
    const matches = arr2.find( r2 => 
      r2.project_id === project.id
      )
    return matches ? { ...project, ...matches } : project
  })
)
```

But I'm not able to make it worth perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way of doing it. once it is written it is easy to follow.

```js
let arr1 = [
    { name:"Elvira", projects_list: [ { id:1 }, { id:2 } ] },
    { name:"Sarah", projects_list: [ { id:2 }, { id:5 } ] },
];

let arr2 = [
    { project_id:1, title: "title_1" },
    { project_id:2, title: "title_2" },
];

arr1.forEach(function(person) {
  person.projects_list.forEach(function(project) {
    var other_project = arr2.find(function(item) {
      return item.project_id == project.id
    })
    if (other_project) {
      project = Object.assign(project, other_project)
      delete project.id;
    }
  })
})

console.log(arr1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. I was completely stuck in the last part. Thanks a lot!